# git: checking out a branch over existing files without overwriting them

Tags: git

We are moving a repository from another SCM to git. That in itself is not a problem, but I need to provide simple instructions to my users on how check can migrate their repository clones (bear in mind that most of my users are non-programmers and only have very basic terminal knowledge).

I was hoping that migration could be done like follows:

1. Go to the folder with your checkout files
2. Run `git init`
3. Connect to the remote repository `git remote add origin URL`
4. Synchronise the data `git fetch`
5. Check out the files `git checkout master`

Now, my issue is with step 5, as git complains about "...untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout". Can I somehow force it to check out the branch *without* overwriting the files (e.g. treating any differences in files them as local changes applied post-checkout)? My current SCM will correctly detect which files are different would actually be overwritten and asks for user choice on what to do — I expected git to have similar functionality.

Basically, what I want is to tell git "you are now on latest master checkout, period. Don't do anything to the files". Is there a sane way of accomplishing it? Of course, I can always ask my users to make another clone and copy their old files over it, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You can't/won't want to do this, because the untracked files which are they would either be overwritten by Git, or they stay put and then they are not in sync with the new branch/repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `git checkout master`, you can try :

```
git reset origin/master
```

Then instruct them on how to inspect the diff.

Comment: Unfortunately this marks all the files as deleted... basically, it stops tracking the files. No idea why.

Comment: Hmm, then try a plain `git reset` (it is a shortcut for `--mixed`, and it won't modify the files on disk either)  -- the only one to avoid at all cost is : `git reset --hard`

Comment: `git reset origin/master` did the trick. Can't believe I didn't try it out :) Thank you!

Comment: You will probably want to have them to run a "add all files" (`git add -A`) afterwards anyway